# Parsing Json with jQuery found difficult

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, for-loop, format

Json object (parameters)

```
"selectedShopeNumber":1765653589, "shopeNumbersForSelectedNames":[], "shopeNumbers":[1765653589, 660791222],"shopeNames":["Shope 1","Shope 2"]
```

code

```
var params = JSON.parse("[" + parameters + "]");
for (var i = 0; i < params.shopeNumbers.length; i++) {
    var thisShopeDiv = $(params.shopeNumbers[i].toString());
    var thisShopeHeader = thisShopeDiv.getFirstElementByClassName('shopeHeader');

    // observe the shope header for changing shopes and highlighting the 'tab'
    Event.bind(thisShopeHeader, 'click', this.switchShope.bindAsEventListener(this, params.shopeNumbers[i]));
    Event.bind(thisShopeHeader, 'mouseover', this.hoverHeader.bindAsEventListener(this, thisShopeHeader, 'on'));
    Event.bind(thisShopeHeader, 'mouseout', this.hoverHeader.bindAsEventListener(this, thisShopeHeader, 'off'));

    // initialize this shopeSet
    this.initShopeSet(thisShopeDiv, params.shopeNumbers[i], params.shopeNames[i]);
}

    this.shopeObj[shopeId] = {};
    var flt = this.shopeObj[shopeId];
```

Getting an **error** like

> **params.shopeNumbers is undefined**

Have tried a lot with json parsing.
The JSON object is coming from server. So can't change from there.

I am ready to change the forloop format. - that too i tried.
I also tried making the jsonObject as `parameters="{"+parameters+"}"` including at the starting itself.

i think it will work if we can make the parameters as:

```
parameters = "{ results :"+parameters+"}"
```

and then calling the same by using "results" object

Is there any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is wrong :

What type `parameters` is ? it's certainly not a string. it is an object.

[image]

Then , no `parse` is needed. your data is not a string json representation.

Do this instead :

`var params =  parameters ;`

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/gbrnD/

```
var params = {  "selectedShopeNumber":1765653589, "shopeNumbersForSelectedNames":[], "shopeNumbers":[1765653589, 660791222],"shopeNames":["Shope 1","Shope 2"]  };

for (var i = 0; i < params.shopeNumbers.length; i++) {
    var thisShopeDiv = params.shopeNumbers[i].toString();



  alert(thisShopeDiv);
 }
```